# ST2.1 - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'link'

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I've just tried to upgrade my ST2.0 source files of my application to ST2.1 by copying over all the javascript files in my project in the 'src' folder. When I load the first screen I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'link'

Is there a standard way to upgrade to 2.1?  Any ideas why am I getting this error?

It seems to be happening in container.js, at  this point in code:

```
 updateUseBodyElement: function(useBodyElement) {
        if (useBodyElement) {
            this.link('bodyElement', this.innerElement.wrap({
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'link'
                cls: 'x-body'
            }));
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The src folder for 2.1 is different, you cannot upgrade by just copying over the files.

This is the site I used to get my app upgraded.

http://senchatouchexp.blogspot.com/2012/12/sencha-touch-20x-upgrade-21.html